# Code working in console but not in terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I will try to be as specific as possible since I'm a beginner and it's my first question here on stackoverflow :) !

I'm trying to extract the value of some data attribute in a html page, using cheerio and nodeJs, here is my code:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var url = 'http://www.example.com/example';
    request(url, function(err, resp, body){
    var dataList = $(".example").map(function() {
    return $(this).data("example");
 }).get();

console.log(dataList.join("|"));
});
```

and here is the html I'm working on:

```
<span class="item-link"><span class="example" data-mel="example">
                          <img src="/#" alt="" />
            </span></span>
```

So the issue I have is that when I try to run my code in my terminal I get this error: [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dcrdl.png)

But when I run this part in console chrome :

```
  var dataList = $(".mel").map(function() {
  return $(this).data("mel");
  }).get();

  console.log(dataList.join("|"));
```

it works !!! :( But i want to run it in my terminal so i can iterate!

So I managed to make it work in my terminal with this code:

```
var request = require("request"),
cheerio = require("cheerio"),
url = "http://www.example.com/example";
var mail2 = [];

request(url, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error) {
   var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    $('.item-link').each(function(i, elem){
     mail2[i] = $(".example").data("example");
    });
  console.log(mail2.join(', '));
```

But then I get the same element again and again and it doesn't extract the whole page.

Sorry for this big mess, let me know if I can be more specific!!
And please excuse my English C: !

Thanks :-)

Comment: Why didn’t you use the same approach with `$(".example")` map in your working version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching your code to:

```
var request = require("request"),
cheerio = require("cheerio"),
url = "http://www.example.com/example";
var mail2 = [];

request(url, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error) {
   var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    $('.item-link').each(function(i, elem){
      mail2[i] = $(elem).find(".example").data("example");
    });
  }
});
console.log(mail2.join(', '));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man it works !! 

I'm trying to understand why my previous code didn't work but i can't get it, any idea ?

Comment: $(".example") always get's an array of all the elements on the page with that class, but if you call a function on it which is supposed to work with one element ( ex: data(), val(), html() ) then it will run that on the first element of the array.
You need to use the current element in the iteration $(elem), and find your class inside that

Comment: @gvdh could you please accept my answer if it solved your problem? :) I'm trying to get some reputation on Stackoverflow, and every bit counts